# type="text/javascript" attribute is missing in view page source

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

i copy paste a ad script code in header.php but 'type' attribute is missing in view page source, and it cause ads are not displayed.
how can i solve that problem?

it's not because of plugins When I change the theme, There is no problem

Comment: A missing `type` attribute, [would default to the content being JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type#attribute_is_not_set_default_an_empty_string_or_a_javascript_mime_type), so this shouldn't be a problem.